# MSOLAP Version 15.1.6x.2x

Tags: powerbi, ssms, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

I am trying to find installer for MSOLAP Version 15.1.6x.2x, which is an older version of what is currently available from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=azure-analysis-services-current#download-the-latest-client-libraries-windows-installer).

I have scoured internet and I am not able to find this version for download. The newer version doesn't work with the solution I currently have. SSMS apparently installs this driver but SSMS is not an option in my case.

Can anyone point where this driver might be available?

Comment: I too require this to fix this issue: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1820

Answer (score 0):

You can get older versions from the SQL Server Feature Packs, eg
[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Service Pack 3 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103444#)

Comment: Tried installing sql server feature packs but they only installed ODBD driver. I am trying to find standalone installer of Microsoft Analysis Services OLE DB Provider (MSOLAP) version 15.1.xx.xx and not having any luck at all

Comment: Did you install the SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi package?

Comment: Tried again with 2014 and 2016 feature packs. Both of them had SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi packages, but were older version not compatible for my solution. I believe 2017 and higher might be the right packages, but unfortunately they don't have SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi packages.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the approach suggested by Sanch as I was unable find the installer for the driver that I needed